# Подскажите как получить данные с json

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пож. как получить поле FullName?
Пробовал resultApi.Data.FullName, но результат undefined(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
getApiCryptocompare() {
  setInterval(async() => {
    const inquiryApi = await fetch ('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist?summary=true')
  let resultApi = await inquiryApi.json();
   console.log(resultApi);
  }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: `resultApi.Data['0XBTC'].FullName`

Comment: Большое спасибо, только уточнение, нужны все ключи FullName

Comment: `Object.keys(resultApi.Data).map(e => resultApi.Data[e].FullName)`

Comment: @entithat  Большое спасибо)

Comment: @entithat я уже перепробовал кучу методов, и спред использовал, не получалось(

Comment: ну спрэд тут никак